# HIVE: Invalid column reference on INSERT. Works in select, not when combined with insert

Tags: hadoop, select, group-by, insert, hive

Context: I am working for a university on a project comparing their current setup (Oracle) to Hadoop / Hive and am trying to recreate some tables for my report.

I am trying to insert into a table that I have created using hive. I am trying to insert rows that are grabbed using a SELECT statement on another table. If I Just run the select statement, I get all of the rows. However when I put this select into the insert statement I get an error:

> SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 102:11 Invalid column reference 'emplid'

Here is my create table / insert / select:

```
CREATE TABLE STG_HCM_PRE_COMP (
  `JOB_DAYSEQ_KEY`          DECIMAL(38,0)
, `DW_COMP_LN_CNT`          Int
, `EMPLID`                  String
, `EMPL_RCD`                Int
, `EFFDT`                   DATE
, `EFFSEQ`                  Int
, `COMP_EFFSEQ`             Int
, `COMP_RATECD`             String
, `COMP_RATECD_DESCR`       String 
, `COMP_RATECD2`            String
, `COMP_RATECD_DESCR2`      String 
, `COMP_RATE_POINTS`        Int
, `COMPRATE`                FLOAT
, `UNITS`                   FLOAT
, `COMP_PCT`                FLOAT
, `COMP_FREQUENCY`          String
, `COMP_FREQUENCY_DESCR`    String 
, `CURRENCY_CD`             String
, `MANUAL_SW`               String
, `CONVERT_COMPRT`          FLOAT
, `RATE_CODE_GROUP`         String
, `RATE_CODE_GROUP_DESCR`   String 
, `CHANGE_AMT`              FLOAT
, `CHANGE_PCT`              FLOAT 
, `CHANGE_PTS`              Int
, `FTE_INDICATOR`           String
, `CMP_SRC_IND`             String
, `CMP_SRC_IND_DESCR`       String 
, `DW_JOB_ID`               String        
, `DW_JOBSEQ`               BIGINT        
, `DW_START_DATE`           DATE      
, `DW_END_DATE`             DATE      
, `DW_CURRENT_IND`          String        
, `DW_SOURCE_DB`            String        
, `DW_CF_YR`                Int       
, `DW_CREATED_EW_DTTM`      DATE       
, `DW_LASTUPD_EW_DTTM`      DATE      
);

INSERT INTO STG_HCM_PRE_COMP 
(
  job_dayseq_key  
, dw_comp_ln_cnt
, emplid        
, empl_rcd      
, effdt         
, effseq       
, comp_effseq   
, comp_ratecd   
, comp_ratecd_descr 
, comp_ratecd2
, comp_ratecd_descr2   
, comp_rate_points
, comprate 
, units
, comp_pct      
, comp_frequency
, comp_frequency_descr  
, currency_cd   
, manual_sw     
, convert_comprt
, rate_code_group   
, rate_code_group_descr 
, change_amt    
, change_pct    
, change_pts    
, fte_indicator  
, cmp_src_ind   
, cmp_src_ind_descr   
, dw_job_id             
, dw_jobseq         
, dw_start_date     
, dw_end_date           
, dw_current_ind
, dw_source_db     
, dw_cf_yr
, dw_created_ew_dttm
, dw_lastupd_ew_dttm
)
SELECT
cast(CONCAT(date_format(c.effdt,'YYYYMMdd'), lpad(cast(cast(c.effseq as int) as string), 4, '0'), c.EMPLID, lpad(cast(cast(c.EMPL_RCD as int) as string), 4, '0')) as decimal(38,0)) as job_dayseq_key
, count(*) over (partition by c.emplid,c.empl_rcd, c.effdt, c.effseq) as dw_comp_ln_cnt
, c.EMPLID
, c.EMPL_RCD
, c.EFFDT
, c.EFFSEQ
, c.COMP_EFFSEQ
, c.COMP_RATECD
, '-'
, '-'
, '-'
, c.COMP_RATE_POINTS
, c.COMPRATE
, cast(null as int)
, c.COMP_PCT
, c.COMP_FREQUENCY
, '-'
, c.CURRENCY_CD
, c.MANUAL_SW
, c.CONVERT_COMPRT
, c.RATE_CODE_GROUP
, '-'
, c.CHANGE_AMT
, c.CHANGE_PCT
, c.CHANGE_PTS
, c.FTE_INDICATOR
, c.CMP_SRC_IND
, NVL(X1.XLATLONGNAME,'-')
, CONCAT(c.EMPLID, '-', lpad(cast(cast(c.EMPL_RCD as int) as string), 4, '0')) as dw_job_id
, dense_rank() over (partition by c.emplid,c.empl_rcd order by c.effdt desc,c.effseq desc) as dw_jobseq
, c.EFFDT as dw_start_date
, LEAD(c.EFFDT,1,TO_DATE('2099-6-30')) OVER (PARTITION BY c.EMPLID, c.EMPL_RCD ORDER BY c.effdt, c.effseq) as dw_end_date
, '-'
, 'DW.DB_CMS_HR'
,  CASE D_DAT.FISCAL_YEAR
        when 2005 then D_DAT.FISCAL_YEAR
        when 2006 then D_DAT.FISCAL_YEAR
        when 2007 then D_DAT.FISCAL_YEAR
        when 2008 then D_DAT.FISCAL_YEAR
        when 2009 then D_DAT.FISCAL_YEAR
        when 2010 then D_DAT.FISCAL_YEAR
        when 2011 then D_DAT.FISCAL_YEAR
        when 2012 then D_DAT.FISCAL_YEAR
        when 2013 then D_DAT.FISCAL_YEAR
        when 2014 then D_DAT.FISCAL_YEAR
        else 2005 end
, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())
, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())


FROM  PS_COMPENSATION C
     ,DW.DIM_DATE D_DAT 
     ,STG_HCM_MAXEFFDT_XLAT X1
WHERE
  c.effdt = d_dat.date_id
  AND c.comp_ratecd != 'UNITS'
  AND X1.FIELDNAME = 'CMP_SRC_IND'
  AND X1.FIELDVALUE = C.CMP_SRC_IND
  AND c.emplid not like 'DUP%'

order by c.EMPLID, c.EMPL_RCD, c.EFFDT, c.EFFSEQ;
```

Any insight as to why this query is failing only when the select is combined with the insert statement would be greatly appreciated!

I have seen several other threads referencing this issue where the author is not including enough columns in the order by buy I have confirmed through sqlDeveloper that the following query returns no rows, meaning that the group by is valid for the select.

```
select emplid,empl_rcd,effdt, EFFSEQ, count(*)
from stg_hcm_pre_comp
group by emplid,empl_rcd,effdt,EFFSEQ
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support for column list specification in INSERT statement started with Hive 1.2.0
In earlier versions you should insert all the columns, by their order in the target table

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9481

Comment: I may not be interpreting this correctly, but I have other inserts like this that work. Difference being without the group by.

For example this query works just fine:
[link](http://pastebin.com/hw3U5TxG_)

Comment: @ConnorCallison - The link seems to be broken

Comment: I ended up removing the columns list and that fixed it (Thanks a ton!). It is interesting how a similar query with a columns list worked previously though. Here is an updated link: [link](https://paste.ofcode.org/p2rnEx6iGxTXgRwy3bk2p3)

Comment: @ConnorCallison - I'll test it later. In the meantime I strongly recommend you'll check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42376268/6336479

Comment: @ConnorCallison Adding Colunm list in insert does not work well with order by clause in select.