# Query runs When I use string as date `2017-06-06` in condition, but doesn't when I try function `from_unixtime`

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a view, which is formed from joining a table(around 25 TB) with another table(5 GB)

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS 
select columns(around 30 columns)
from table1
RIGHT JOIN table2
ON conditions1
where conditions2
```

When I run this select

```
select * 
from view1
where date='20170320'
```

It finishes in a couple of minutes. But this select

```
select * 
from view1
where date = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_add(CURRENT_DATE, -1) ,'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyyMMdd')
```

Takes forever to start(if it starts at all) and doesn't finish. There are no actual errors. It just waits until I get tired and decide to kill it.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your table contains a string, so why are you comparing to a unix time? Does simply `select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_add(CURRENT_DATE, -1) ,'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyyMMdd')` take long?

Comment: @cri `select from_unixtime......` finishes in a few seconds. `comparing to a unix time` How should I do it then?

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot that `from_unixtime` returned strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why partitions elimination does not happen for this query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376268/why-partitions-elimination-does-not-happen-for-this-query)