# How to get previous day date in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am novice to Hive. Trying to get the previous day date using the below query:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM store_rcd_table
WHERE recon_dt = unix_timestamp(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),
'yyyy-MM-dd'),1),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

but getting the NULL as output. The output should have been date(2017-09-23) and MAX(id).

Also tried,

```
Select MAX(id) FROM store_rcd_table
WHERE recon_dt ='2017-09-24';
```

No output for this query also, just OK is coming as an output.

Not getting what the issue is? Any suggestion/ help is appreciated.

The structure of the table is:

```
id              string                                      
locationid      string                                      
mngrid          string                                      
empid           string                                                                          
deleted         boolean                                     
recon_dt        string
```

Comment: What does `SELECT unix_timestamp(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),
'yyyy-MM-dd'),1),'yyyy-MM-dd');` give you?

Comment: Your output is only the max id in both queries. Without seeing the data, it's hard to say it isn't NULL

Comment: @cricket_007 It gives:

    hive> SELECT       unix_timestamp(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-    dd'),1),'yyyy-MM-dd');
    OK
    1506225600
    Time taken: 0.089 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
    hive>

Comment: Looks like yesterday to me. Now, what's the problem?

Comment: desired output is: '2017-09-23'.

Comment: Add a data sample to your original post

Answer (score 9):

Try `select date_sub(current_date, 1);`

```
0: jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2:1> select date_sub(current_date, 1);
+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 2017-09-24  |
+-------------+--+
1 row selected (0.182 seconds)
```

<sub>Original attempt was `date_sub(CAST(unix_timestamp()*1000 AS TIMESTAMP), 1)` but apparently that's wrong. See comments</sub>

Feel free to read up on [Hive Date Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

---

If you get no results, you should check the source data to see what `recon_dt` actually is. (Also worth pointing out that you used two different tables in the question)

Comment: I did that but its not showing. As currently I don't have sufficient reputation points.

Comment: **(1)** `current_date` was introduced on Hive 1.2.0, 18 May 2015, more than 2 years ago. **(2)**  The use of `unix_timestamp` prevents partition elimination.

Comment: The use of unix_timestamp is not legitimate for this scenario

Comment: @Dudu if you can send a reference to partition elimination for Hive, I'll gladly read it. Everything I've found immediately is for SQL Server

Comment: @newbee Upvoting and accepting are different actions. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @cricket_007, from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF: "Gets current Unix timestamp in seconds. This function is not deterministic and its value is not fixed for the scope of a query execution, therefore prevents proper optimization of queries - this has been deprecated since 2.0 in favor of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP constant." (I wrote this... :-) ...)

Comment: @cricket_007, also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376268/why-partitions-elimination-does-not-happen-for-this-query/42377403#42377403. You can see that you don't need to execute anything in order to test partitions elimination, the execution plan is enough.

Comment: @Dudu Makes sense. Thanks. So, what was point (1) about? Should I not be using `current_date`? I haven't had the luxury of using Hive 2.x much.

Comment: Since current_date is here for a long time now, unix_timestamp should be obseleted