# How to find previous date in HIVE

Tags: sql, date, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to find previous date in Hive.

For example   :

I have Date as 20180821 (`yyyyMMdd`) format, I want to find previous date of this in Hive. I tried `date_sub()` function, seems it works only with `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

How to solve my issue. Please help

Comment: What is the meaning of previous date?  Is it `given_date minus 1` or `an immediate previous date that is less than the given_date` which could be `minus 1 or minus 3 or minus 5` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to already provided solution with `unix_timestamp` conversion, please consider also this.
The same conversion using `substr()` looks a little bit longer, but it will work with any dates/timestamps like `'19691231 19:00:00'` without TZ issues, also this is not slower, because not using SimpleDateFormat/etc and not applying TZ.

```
date_sub(concat_ws('-', substr('20180821',1,4), substr('20180821',5,2), substr('20180821',7,2)),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the format to `yyyy-MM-dd` using `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp` on the existing format and then use `date_sub`.

```
date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20180821','yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible Duplicate: [How to get previous day date in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415615/how-to-get-previous-day-date-in-hive)

To answer your question, date_sub will fetch you the previous day record. It works only on your date value in format: yyyy-MM-dd.
Syntax of date_sub is as:
`date_sub(String date, Int days)`

Hence you need to first convert your current date format into `yyyy-MM-dd` format. To achieve this, use the below query:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20180821','yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd' as converted_date_format;
```

Next you apply date_sub to the above result set with a 1 day value to get the previous record.

```
select date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20180821','yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),1) as previous_day;
```

Having said that, if your requirement is to maintain the date format as `yyyyMMdd`, you can apply regex_replace function to remove the '-', as below:

```
select regexp_replace(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20180821','yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),1),'-','') as previous_day_formatted_yyyymmdd;
```

Hope this helps :)